# Fork multi process with only on parent in C

Tags: c, multiprocessing, fork

I have a project in which I have to fork A B C and D process from one parent which is the original program/main() function. I used pipes to communicate between the processes, and I went through a lot of coding, but I wasn't able to send the right messages between the processes. However, I decide to go back to understand the basic concepts of fork() so I wrote the following code.

------Edited: My question is that can I use this template to send messages via pipes from all 4 processes and read those messages from parent? If so in which parent section I have to write the reading code? 
`

```
if (fork()) { //parent log
    printf("Inside parent\n");

    if (fork()) { //parent log
        printf("Inside parent\n");

        if (fork()) { //parent log
            printf("Inside parent\n");

            if (fork()) { //parent log
                printf("Inside parent\n");

            }else { //child process D
                printf("Inside process D\n");
                _exit(1);
            }

        }else { //child process C
            printf("Inside process C\n");
            _exit(1);
        }

    }else { //child process B
        printf("Inside process B\n");
        _exit(1);
    }
}else { //child process A
    printf("Inside process A\n");
    _exit(1);
}
```

My goal is to send messages from A to B and from B to C and from B to D, Also send messages from any process (A B C and D) to the parent.
Is this code template correct? Or there is something wrong with its structure?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: "Is this code template correct?" Did you run it?  What is the output?  This question may be better suited for [CodeReview.SE].

Comment: @JAL Questions asking "Is this code correct?" are not a good fit for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), where questions are expected to work to the best of the asker's knowledge.  Questions seeking a "review" to determine whether or not the code works aren't ready for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: @nhgrif The OP asked "Or there is something wrong with its structure?"  That question (assuming the code works) seems like it would be appropriate for Code Review.

Comment: @JAL and nhgrif, I think it could've been stated better. Assuming the code works and the question is stated better, it could be a good fit. A one-on-one copy would be off-topic.

Comment: Why do you call `_exit()` instead of `exit()`?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves I don't know actually, this my first time working with processes and the code sample from my teacher use _exit(). Is there different?

Comment: That's odd. The difference is that `_exit()` is a syscall and terminates the process immediately - exit handlers registered with `atexit(3)` and `on_exit(3)` will not be called, and stdio buffers will not be flushed. That is generally not desirable, and it's why user code usually exits with the `exit(3)` library function instead.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves I guess because we are doing system programing in this class, so we use system calls a lot

Comment: @Mast Thanks for all replies. The code it worked but I wasn't able to understand how the parent section works. I want to send messages from any child process to the parent, but in the code I have four parent sections. Do all have to be similar? Like if I want the parent section to read messages from process C do I have to write the code in the parent section of C only or in all parent section?

Comment: @NawarYoussef I recommend re-stating the question after reading the [on-topic helpdesk](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and the answers on [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1954/52915) (for maximum effect) on CodeReview.

Comment: @Mast Thanks for the advice, I will do my best to make the questions are smaller and simpler. I will divide my problems into smaller parts and ask questions about them.

Answer (score 2):

While your code does create 4 child processes it can be a lot simpler:

```
int main()
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("getpid = 0x%X\n", getpid());
    if(fork()) {
      printf("Inside parent\n");
    }
    else {
      printf("Inside process %c\n", 'A'+i);
      exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

The key idea is that you can differentiate between each child by the value of `i`.  You can even also use `i` in a `switch` statement:

```
int main()
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("getpid = 0x%X\n", getpid());
    if(fork()) {
      printf("Inside parent\n");
    }
    else {
      switch(i) {
      case 0:
        printf("In process A\n");
        break;
      case 1:
        printf("In process B\n");
        break;
      case 2:
        printf("In process C\n");
        break;
      case 3:
        printf("In process D\n");
        break;
      }
      exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you are right this is much simpler, but I am not sure it will work for my project, because I need to generate 4 processes with only one parent, in the code you posted it looks like I will have four parents, is that correct?

Comment: There is only 1 parent, all the other processes are children of the first process and they don't have any children themselves (unless they call `fork` later on).  You can verify this with the updated version I posted which has a `getpid()`

Comment: ok, I wasn't sure if I will have one parent or many parents. I will write my code based on your answer and I will see if I can get what I want. Thanks